# how to simulate heavy disk / io load for elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, io, load, disk

My task is to make an elastic search disk/io "hard life" :-). To not reinventing the wheel - is there a tool for simulation high disk load on elastic?
what type of query is the most disk/io intensive? I saw many articles and the best practices on how to tune performance but my task is really to kill disk/io for elastic and I didn't find any useful open information on the web.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please shed light on what are you going to achieve with that ? It will help in providing more context.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the elastic's(company behind the elasticsearch) own's benchmarking tool called [Rally](https://github.com/elastic/rally). This is the tool ES people use to show the performance improvement/benchmark against their release.

It has got its [own category on discuss forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/tags/c/elastic-stack/elasticsearch/rally) and also very active users list and development.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JMeter.
there is two article about it :

https://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/09/02/3915

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/elasticsearch-load-testing-learn-how

you should make a dictionary list to search against elasticsearch. because elasticsearch cache last 250 query.

Comment: could you point to any article where its mentioned that ES caches last 250 queries? also I m aware of shard request cache https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html but its also works in very specific cases

Comment: @PrernaGupta https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2017/07/10/caching_in_elasticsearch/

Comment: maybe in later version this config has been changed or increased